# What matrix groups can be embedded in $Sp_4$?

Tags: lie-groups, gr.group-theory, matrices, nt.number-theory

In a [joint paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3322) with Yifan Yang we constructed an "exotic" embedding
of $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ in $Sp_4(\mathbb R)$ (in fact, of $PSL_2(\mathbb R)$ in $PSp_4(\mathbb R)$),
namely,
$$
\iota\colon\begin{pmatrix} a & b \cr c & d \end{pmatrix}
\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}
a^2d+2abc & -3a^2c & abd+\frac12b^2c & \frac12b^2d \cr
-a^2b & a^3 & -\frac12ab^2 & -\frac16b^3 \cr
4acd+2bc^2 & -6ac^2 & ad^2+2bcd & bd^2 \cr
6c^2d & -6c^3 & 3cd^2 & d^3 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
An equivalent form of the embedding was independently discovered by Don Zagier,
and we could not find it in the literature.

Although the properties of the embedding (discussed in the preprint above) are nice by themselves,
I am interested in an exhaustive list of possibilities to embed
other matrix groups and their direct products in $Sp_4(\mathbb R)$ (or $PSp_4(\mathbb R)$).
For example, can the direct product of two copies of $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ be embedded?

As I am not a specialist in Lie groups, I would appreciate plainer sources.
Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Isn't it enough to check whether the group has a 4-dimensional representation V such that \Lambda^2(V) has positive dimension?

Comment: Also, related, if you haven't seen it: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9378/whats-the-classification-of-the-algebraic-subgroups-of-sp4-r

Comment: @Wadim: are you asking whether SL_2(R) x SL_2(R) embeds into Sp_4(R)? Isn't this obvious? SL_2(R) acts on R^2 and preserves an alternating form. So SL_2(R) x SL_2(R) acts on R^4 and preserves an alternating form---just take the direct sum. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can't you can embed $Sp_2(\mathbb{C})$ in $Sp_4(\mathbb{R})$, as a 2- dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ is 4-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$? 

Comment: PS there are several different "explicit" Sp_4's in the literature---different people take different explicit alternating forms. So I think it's good practice to say explicitly what your J is if you're going to write down explicit matrices as in the question. 

Comment: Qiaochu, thanks a lot for the link! I'll definitely follow it (although Matheus's motivation was different he mentioned Don's example). The examples of Greg are given in Vinberg's book but I really wish to have them as (analytically) explicit as possible; that's why I indicate the example which is far from the standard embedding of $SL_2$ in $Sp_4$. Let me check more with 9378...

Comment: The J for the example above is standard $[0,-E;E,0]$.

Comment: @Wadim: pick up any paper by Jacques Tilouine, who has worked with Sp_4 for decades, to see what he thinks is "standard" ;-)

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for the hint (I've never heard of Tilouine)! I don't mind about different standards, but if he has the embeddings explicitly it would be really great to me. Greg's answer to the older question is only quantitative.

Comment: @Michael: I can't embed $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ in $Sp_4(\mathbb R)$ but can in $SL_4(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Tilouine is a master of automorphic forms on Sp_4 (so, the number theory of Sp_4, not the group theory). I think he likes his J to be anti-diagonal because then I *think* it makes the standard parabolic subgroups a bit nicer-looking? Of course you can easily move from one form to the other via some conjugation. I don't know if Tilouine would know too much about these exotic SL_2's though.


Comment: @Wadim: Take a 2-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with an alternating form $B$. Then $V$ is also 4-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$ and if you compose $B$ with the trace map from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ you get an alternating from $B': V\times V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Any element of $Sp_2(\mathbb{C})$ preserving $B$ will also preserve $B'$ and so you embed $Sp_2(\mathbb{C})$ in $Sp_4(\mathbb{R})$. Moreover, this gives an irreducible subgroup of $Sp_4(\mathbb{R})$. This construction definitely holds for finite fields and would also seem to be the case here.

Comment: Kevin: Yes, he is anti-diagonal. And he has a lot of stuff of $p$-adic Siegel modular forms which are of independent interest to me. Thanks for mentioning this treasury of read.

Comment: @Michael: sounds very convincing and interesting, especially since the real dimension of $SL_2(\mathbb C)$ is 6...

Comment: @ Wadim: see the paper http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=IID&s1=799070&vfpref=html&r=3&mx-pid=2476637

Comment: Thanks, Michael! Phantastic (and surprisingly very closed to me, * New Zealand J. Math.*) The abstract sounds very promising.

Comment: @Wadim: In my opinion, you re-discovered the standard 4-dimensional irreducible representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ on the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree 3 in 2 variables. 
Also: the root system of $Sp_4(\mathbb{R})$ is $C_2$, consisting of the 8 vectors $\pm 2e_i,\pm e_i\pm e_j$ in the plane. By Jacobson-Morozov each pair of opposite roots gives you a (non-constant) homomorphism $SL_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow SP_4(\mathbb{R})$. See also: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22186/jacobson-morozov-on-the-algebraic-group-level

Answer (score 2):

You can embed the direct product of two copies of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$. One embedding sends the entries to the center $2\times2$ block, the other sends the entries to the corners with the $2\times2$ identity matrix in the center block. Here, the $J$ matrix is the standard anti-diagonal matrix

For embeddings of other groups, you could look at the Bruhat decomposition of Sp(4) and write a decomposition of each cell. Some explicit information is given on the decomposition for GSp(4) in a [book](http://www.math.ou.edu/~rschmidt/papers/NF.pdf) by Ralf Schmidt and Brooks Roberts, which is available on Ralf's website.